# Docker - Share volume between containers in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 dockerised services, created with `docker-compose`. A backend one with `python` and a web one with `php` and `apache`. My `.yaml` file looks like this:

```
services:

  web:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php_web
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    
  python:
    build: ./python
    volumes:
      - ./product:/user/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I would like to be able to access the web container filesystem from the python one and vice versa, so they can share files.

Is there a simple way to do this with docker compose?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: I have read through the docs but don't understand how to make a volume that both containers can access

Comment: `But, if you want to reuse a volume across multiple services, then define a named volume in the top-level volumes key.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a volume in docker:

```
docker volume create php-volume
```

Then, declare at the top-level of your docker-compose file, like this:

```
services:

  web:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php_web
    volumes:
      - php-volume:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  python:
    build: ./python
    volumes:
      - ./product:/user/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

volumes:
  php-volume:
```